# Where is my database in ASP.NET MVC5 Azure AD Web App template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-active-directory

**Background to Question:-**

I'm learning about using Azure AD as an authentication method for ASP.NET MVC 5 web applications (as opposed to standard local authentication using Identity).

With VS2015, I've used the template for MVC 5 web app and selected "Work and School Accounts" in the Change Authentication menu...

I have created a domain/users in my Azure account and successfully manage to authenticate when I run the default application.

However:-

I've noticed that there is no local database to migrate to Azure (which I thought was required to store tenant/token information). Furthermore, Web.config has no default connection string defined (there was one in the "Individual Accounts" template)

**The Question**

Why does this template have no default database? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database dependency for Work/School account authentication with Azure AD was removed in the new templates.  The experience you indicated you used to see is the experience as documented [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) in the older project templates.

The older templates used WS-Federation and the WS-Federation endpoint from Azure AD to authenticate users.  The database was used to store a little bit of Azure AD tenant information and a certificate thumbprint used to validate SAML tokens issued by Azure AD.  If you're interested in knowing more about this I blogged about it [here](http://rickrainey.com/2014/08/19/deep-dive-azure-websites-and-organizational-authentication-using-azure-ad/).

The new templates use OWIN middleware and OpenID Connect to authenticate users.  OpenID Connect is built upon OAuth 2.0 and therefore uses the OAuth endpoints from Azure AD.  You still get Work/School account authentication as you have observed.  It's just accomplished using different protocols, libraries, and token formats (JWT instead of SAML) than what you've seen in the past.  If you look in Startup.Auth.cs you will see where this gets wired up.

[image]

The lack of a database dependency in these newer templates just to support work/school account authentication is a ***good thing***.  In this model, the certificate thumbprint used to validate tokens is retrieved at the time the user is authenticated (via the WS-Federation Metadata Endpoint) rather than loaded into your application from a database.

If you want a database, you can certainly add one for your application to use.  But, thankfully, it's not required for authenticating users.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear.I think I need to understand more about OpenID Connect, whether I need to do anything with the JWT token and how I should handle claims...

Comment: BTW, something I just noticed today is that if you select the option in the template to use the Azure AD Graph, then the database dependency is added in this scenario. Not really sure why but I wanted to mention it since it just in case you see this in a future project.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, the reason it is added if you choose the options to access the Azure AD graph is because it provides an ADAL Token Cache implementation.  This implementation uses the database to cache the token, avoiding unnecessary trips to Azure AD during calls to AcquireToken.  Again, this doesn't change your question or my answer, but it is good to know should you check these options in the future.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'll stick ADAL on my list of things to read about :)

Comment: Actually, I can't find the option to use the Azure AD Graph in the template... which template should I be using?